# How to pass array<int, 6> to function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Thank you in advance!

So I am trying to pass an array to a function but I am having trouble.

My array is declared as follows:

```
array<int, 6> yourNumbers {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

I'm trying to pass it to a function to be checked for duplicate numbers. I'm doing it this way because I want one function that can be reused to check different arrays. Any input?

This is the code I have so far. But you can see in the checkPrevNum() function it is limited to iterating through the predetermined array randomNums. I want it so that I can pass any array that I want to the function to be checked. I'm relatively new to C/C++.

```
int getNum(){
int numSelection = 0;

do {
numSelection = (rand() % 69) + 1;
} while (checkPrevNum(numSelection) == true);

return numSelection;
}

bool checkPrevNum(int prevNum){
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (prevNum == randomNums[i]){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: How are you passing it to the function that isn't working?  What errors do you get?

Answer (score 2):

`array<int, 6>` is a distinct static type from say `array<int, 7>`, so a templated function would be needed to handle either directly:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void check_duplicates(const std::array<T, N>& a)
    ...
```

Alternatively, the caller could pass a pointer to the first element and a size.  If you only need to support one element type:

```
void check_duplicates_2(const int*, size_t n)
    ...

// caller:
check_duplicates_2(&yourNumbers[0], yourNumbers.size());
```

If you want to support different types:

```
template <typename T>
void check_duplicates_3(const T*, size_t n)
    ...

// caller:
check_duplicates_3(&yourNumbers[0], yourNumbers.size());
```

---

If the `check_duplicates` function implementation is particularly long, and you're calling it with many distinct array sizes, you may want to use a layered approach to minimise code bloat:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void check_duplicates(const std::array<T, N>& a)
    { return check_duplicates_3(&a[0], a.size()); }
```